# how to pass '?' character in url (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters

i want to pass a query to url like 
http:/localhost:3000/saldo/;1010917745800000015?1

in my routes i have:

```
get 'saldo/:nomor' => 'kartus#show_saldo' , as: :show_saldo
```

and controller:

```
def show_saldo
  @kartu = Kartu.find_by_nomor(params[:nomor])
end
```

but instead i get this params

```
Parameters {"1"=> nil,"nomor"=>";1010917745800000015"}
```

how can i get my param as `{"nomor"=>";1010917745800000015?1"}`

Comment: what is you link_to?? Please update your question with html code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to 'xyz' show_saldo_path(:nomor => 'nomor', :def => 'def'......) %>
```

In get everything you passed other than url parameter will become your query parameter. `def` will become your url parameter. More information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Comment: You will get second parameter in your controller. Params[:params_name].

Answer (score 2):

`?` is a special character in urls.  If you want to include it in the value of a parameter then you should **Uri Encode**, eg with `CGI.escape()`, the parameter before submitting it: this will convert "?" to "%3F", and will similarly convert any other special characters (spaces, brackets etc).  So, the parameter that is actually submitted will become "%3B1010917745800000015%3F1".

At the server side, rails will call CGI.unescape on the params, so it should show up in your controller as ";1010917745800000015?1" again.

This should happen automatically with form inputs - ie, if someone writes `;1010917745800000015?1` into a text field then it should actually be sent through as `"%3B1010917745800000015%3F1"`

If you want people to diagnose why this isn't happening then you should include the html (of the form or link which is submitting this value) to your question.

Comment: what gem can i include in my controller to encode the Uri?

Comment: i use CGI.escape(params[:nomor]) in my controller,but it only escape the passed params. how to escape it before the params get passed in to controller

Comment: Can you include the code for the form, or whatever is passing this through, please, as an EDIT to your question.